# using cm in responsive media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using centimeter in my CSS media queries to make my template responsive, while these days we have smartphones with very high resolutions that makes pixel filters difficult.
my question is that why all websites don't use CM which makes responsive much more easy and functional? is there anything going to be missed by using cm that I don't know?

Edit: I'm using `min-**device**-width` as a media query.

Comment: Why would you even want to use cm?

Comment: because if I use pixels, then for example HTC One with 1920x1080px resolution will show template in desktop styles, while it's a mobile with small screen

Comment: I'm with you @Payam. I cannot understand how 1cm is not always 1cm. I find REAL units the best way to measure what one shows in the screen. Logo for 4" phone, 1cm. Logo for 27" desktop, 3cm. Period.

Answer (score 17):

I'd been also keen on using physical units for CSS measurements, as it makes a lot of sense, specifically for designing reading experience of long form content on all types of devices.
But the problem with this approach is that 1 CSS cm/in is absolutely not the same as 1 cm/in in the real world.
Just try making a box with width and height of 1cm, and then measure the rendering in different browsers, screens and devices. You may be unhappily surprised.

The fundamental problem is that all (? well most) devices render physical units as (surprise) an equation of 1in = 96px (or 1cm = ~37.8px). So if you define your units or media queries in cm, that virtually means you define them in ~37.8 pixels ratio, which in most cases certainly is not what you want to.

---

Comment: Here's a [full chart of conversions](http://destination-code.blogspot.com/2008/10/font-size-absolute-length-units-pt-pc.html)

Answer (score 6):

There's really no benefit in using cm over px.

One of the [official CSS3 Candidate Recommendations](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) defines these absolute lengths:

```
unit    definition
‘cm’    centimeters
‘mm’    millimeters
‘in’    inches; 1in is equal to 2.54cm
‘px’    pixels; 1px is equal to 1/96th of 1in
‘pt’    points; 1pt is equal to 1/72nd of 1in
‘pc’    picas; 1pc is equal to 12pt
```

Therefore 1cm is roughly equal to 37.80px. If a device's screen width measures 10cm, then in pixels this is roughly 378px.

Note here how I've said "device width". Media queries support 2 different width and height queries: `min-width` and `min-height` are based on the screen's resolution; `min-device-width` and `min-device-height` are based on the size of the screen.

You can refer to the official [Media Queries documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) for further information.

Comment: yeah I forgot to say I'm using `min-device-width` and now I have mobile styles shown in HTC One with high resolution and an old smart phone with low resolution. how this is not a benefit ?

Comment: I think this article can put you a lot of light on this kind of topic http://demosthenes.info/blog/775/Which-CSS-Measurements-To-Use-When

Answer (score 0):

This is still actual in 2018. And I strongly recommend using `rem`, `em` in your layout. Yes, its size varies from device to device, but this is its beauty, since you shouldn't decide "if 2cm for logo width is enough?" Remember that user can increase font-size manually because your 2cm-decision wasn't enough. 
Also it's much more intuitive to measure text blocks in `em`s, rather than `cm`s because you answer the question "how many symbols should be in a line".

Answer (score -1):

I think it is great. Even if centimeters are directly equivalent to pixels (which I am not sure is the case), it is more readable and makes more sense in using them. I've used them, but the thing is, browser compatibility doesn't seem to be great for these units, at first view.